# Rendering text with SDL2, problems updating texture / output

Tags: c++, sdl-2, text-rendering

I have recently started using SDL2 in a C++ project, which is mainly used as a training project so I can learn using SDL2.
One of the things I tried, was to write a simple label class. The Idea is that the label is created with given position and dimensions at start. Then when I call my 'setText()' function, the text would be rendered and shown on window. At first I used this approach:

```
// get a surface from given text    
m_surf = TTF_RenderText_Solid(m_font, txt.c_str(), fgCol);
// get a texture from the previous surface  
m_texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(r, m_surf);
// render it in 'r' which is the window renderer
SDL_RenderCopy(r, m_texture, NULL, &rect);
```

This works for me. So I thought to remove the overhead of creating textures every time text changes, then destroy them, and use `SDL_UpdateTexture()`. 
Well, this never worked! It always produces a corrupt output on screen, even though the call is successful:

```
// Once at ctor create a texture
m_texture = SDL_CreateTexture(r, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA32,SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STATIC, rect.w, rect.h);
// ...
// later update when setText() is called get a surface from given text and update texture   
m_surf = TTF_RenderText_Solid(m_font, txt.c_str(), fgCol);
rc = SDL_UpdateTexture(m_texture,  NULL, m_surf->pixels, m_surf->pitch);
```

My first thought was that it's something wrong with the pixel formatting... so I also used a format convert before updating:
`m_surf =  SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat(ts, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA32, 0);`
where 'ts' is a temp surface where the text was rendered, and constant SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA32 is same as the one I used to create the m_texture.

here  is what I get on window when using 'SDL_UpdateTexture()'
[image: corrupt output]

Any Ideas ?

Thank you,
Alex

Code Snip:
I have written a compact piece of code that is related to reproduce problem

```
// label class declaration
class label
{
    friend class panel;
    public:
        label(SDL_Window* const w, TTF_Font* const fnt, SDL_Rect rect);
        ~label();

        int draw(SDL_Rect& rect);
        int draw(SDL_Rect& rect,const std::string& txt, SDL_Color fgCol, int quality);

    private:
    std::string     m_txt;
    TTF_Font* const m_font = nullptr;
    SDL_Surface     *m_surf = nullptr;
    SDL_Texture     *m_texture = nullptr;
    SDL_Rect        m_rect{0,0,0,0};
    SDL_Renderer    *m_ren;
    SDL_Window      *m_wnd;
    Uint32          m_pixForm;
};

// label class constructor
label::label(SDL_Window* const w, TTF_Font* const fnt, SDL_Rect rect):m_wnd(w),m_font(fnt),m_surf (nullptr), m_rect(rect)
{
// save window info locally for label object
    m_ren =SDL_GetRenderer(m_wnd);
    m_pixForm =SDL_GetWindowPixelFormat(m_wnd);
    m_texture = SDL_CreateTexture(m_ren, m_pixForm,SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STATIC, rect.w, rect.h);
    m_surf = nullptr;
    std::cout << "PixelFormat " << m_pixForm << " : " << SDL_GetPixelFormatName(m_pixForm) <<  std::endl;
}

// label class methods to render/draw text on screen
int label::setText(const std::string& txt, SDL_Color fgCol, int quality=0)
{
    int w,h;
    SDL_Surface *ts;
    if(m_surf!=nullptr)SDL_FreeSurface(m_surf);
    switch(quality)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            ts = TTF_RenderText_Shaded(m_font, txt.c_str(), fgCol, SDL_Color{0,0,0,0});
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            ts = TTF_RenderText_Blended(m_font,txt.c_str(), fgCol);
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            ts = TTF_RenderText_Solid(m_font, txt.c_str(), fgCol);
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Before pixFormat ts " << SDL_GetPixelFormatName(ts->format->format)<< std::endl;
    m_surf =  SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat(ts, m_pixForm, 0);
    std::cout << "After pixFormat surf : " <<  SDL_GetPixelFormatName(m_surf->format->format) << " ts " << SDL_GetPixelFormatName(ts->format->format)<< std::endl;
    SDL_FreeSurface(ts);
    TTF_SizeText(m_font, txt.c_str(), &w, &h);
    std::cout << "Set text '" << txt << "' w: " << w << " h: " << h << std::endl;
}

int label::draw(SDL_Rect& rect)
{
    // HERE is the one that draw the noise on screen!
    {
        int rc;
        rc = SDL_UpdateTexture(m_texture,  NULL, m_surf->pixels, m_surf->pitch);
        if(rc)
        {
            std::cout << "Error updating texture " << rc <<std::endl;
            return(rc);
        }
    }
    // if it is replaced with the following it works:
    /*
    {
        if(m_texture!=nullptr)SDL_DestroyTexture(m_texture);
        m_texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(r, m_surf);
    }
    */

    SDL_RenderCopy(m_ren, m_texture, NULL, &rect);
}

int label::draw(SDL_Rect& rect,const std::string& txt, SDL_Color fgCol, int q)
{
    setText(txt,fgCol,q);
    draw(rect);
}

// main functiom. Init SDL, create window, create label and draw it:
int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    SDL_Window *wnd ;
    SDL_Renderer *wrend;
    int i;

    wnd = SDL_CreateWindow("TestWin",SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,500,300,0);
    wrend = SDL_CreateRenderer(wnd,-1,SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(wrend,SDL_BLENDMODE_ADD);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(wrend,0,0,0,255);
    SDL_RenderClear(wrend);

    SDL_Color fcol{255,255,0,128};
    SDL_Rect lblBox;
    lblBox.h = 120;
    lblBox.w = 280;
    lblBox.x = 1;
    lblBox.y = 1;

    label lbl(wnd, getCurrentFont(), lblBox); // create a label (getCurrentFont returns a valid TTF_Font pointer)
    lbl.draw(lblBox,std::string("Text Test"), fcol, 2);
    SDL_RenderPresent(wrend);
    SDL_ShowWindow(wnd);
    // .. more code here
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is just RGB? those color channels look shifted.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure I understood your comment. If you noticed, I used `SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat()` to make sure that the surface created from text rendering matches the pixelFormat of the texture it is going into. is this what you mean?

Comment: Surface is created at `TTF_RenderText_Solid` invocation and its format does not necessary match texture format at all.

Comment: That is what I also suspect, but in what aspect don't they match? Eventually, it would be a valid SDL2 Surface so since SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface() handles it correctly, I would expect SDL_UpdateTexture() to handle it too, or at least with one more conversion step, such as the one I used calling SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat() before SDL_UpdateTexture(). Am I thinkig this wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. You can assume available SDL libraries.

Comment: Added code in question, as a  minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code on MacOS Catalina and last version of SDL2 and SDL2_ttf and had *segmentation fault*.

After debugging I found that in `label::setText()` you use a quality parameter and if you pass quality=2 (to use the function `TTF_RenderText_Blended()`), you will end up with a segmentation fault or garbage pixels.

But functions `TTF_RenderText_Shaded()` and `TTF_RenderText_Solid()` work well, I think this is directly linked to the fact that with `TTF_RenderText_Blended(`) you have **transparency** in your surface.

**Edit:**
After digging a bit more I solved the *segmentation fault* I had previously by replacing the NULL value for the rect in line :

```
 rc = SDL_UpdateTexture(m_texture,  NULL, m_surf->pixels, m_surf->pitch);
```

by the size of m_surf:

```
SDL_Rect SurfRect;

SurfRect.x = 0;
SurfRect.y = 0;
SurfRect.w = m_surf->w;
SurfRect.h = m_surf->h;
...
rc = SDL_UpdateTexture(m_texture, SurfRect, m_surf->pixels, m_surf->pitch);
```

**Edit 2 :**
I directly look into the source file of the SDL2 to understand what was the difference between my tests and the code done internally by the function `SDL_CreateTexture()` and you have to add these lines :

```
int rc = SDL_UpdateTexture(m_texture, &SurfRect, m_surf->pixels, m_surf->pitch);
{
    Uint8 r, g, b, a;
    SDL_BlendMode blendMode;
    SDL_GetSurfaceColorMod(m_surf, &r, &g, &b);
    SDL_SetTextureColorMod(m_texture, r, g, b);

    SDL_GetSurfaceAlphaMod(m_surf, &a);
    SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod(m_texture, a);

    if (SDL_HasColorKey(m_surf)) {
        /* We converted to a texture with alpha format */
        SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(m_texture, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
    } else {
        SDL_GetSurfaceBlendMode(m_surf, &blendMode);
        SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(m_texture, blendMode);
    }
}
```

[image: Result for TTF_RenderText_Blended()]
Find [here](https://pastebin.com/sDNd0rU8) my raw debug file (this isn't pretty)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to try! I run on Linux, specifically raspbian, the latest raspberry (buster) OS. I don't get a segfault, but this may be random on different platforms, depending on the memory corruption. The important clue here is that I always get the exact same pattern of noise, despite quality setting. I try quality = 0,1,2 . All produce same pattern of pixels.

Comment: @Sagi2313 I fix the segmentation fault I had, see edit section in my anwser, the result isn't the good one but i'm closer :)

Comment: @Sagi2313 I found the solution, see **Edit 2** section :)

Comment: Hello again, unfortunately, I still get the noise instead of text. I was sort of suspecting that, since in your  tests, you had quality 0,1 working from the first moment, and just got trouble with 2. In my case, regardless of quality value, I always got same output. Thank you for spending time on it tho!

Comment: @Sagi2313 In my debug file (available via the link in my answer) I did other modifications like add `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)` and `TTF_Init()`, please check the differences between my working debug file and your version. I think you're gonna make it work.

Comment: @Sagi2313 maybe also add a call to `SDL_SetMainReady();` (https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetMainReady)